# Unable to customize .net core CSRF Cookie Path

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-1.1

In order to be compliant with a security Audit , we need to change the path of the cookies created in our Asp.net core website on dotnet core 1.1

As per my understanding the Antiforgery middleware is automatically injected on using `.AddMvc()`.
I am trying to override the cookie path, by using the below code in Startup.cs

```cs
services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
            {
                options.CookieDomain = "somedefaultName.com";
                options.CookieName = "X-CSRF-TOKEN-COOKIENAME";
                options.CookiePath = "/Path";
                options.FormFieldName = "AntiforgeryFieldname";
                options.HeaderName = "X-CSRF-TOKEN-HEADERNAME";
                options.RequireSsl = false;
                options.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = false;

            });
```

But getting the below error on login to the application. The method is decorated with `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`

info:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter[1]
>         Antiforgery token validation failed. The required antiforgery cookie "X-CSRF-TOKEN-COOKIENAME" is not present.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The
>   required antiforgery cookie "X-CSRF-TOKEN-COOKIENAME" is not present

Comment: Have you Configured antiforgery features with IAntiforgery??

Comment: No I am using the [ValidateAntiForgery] atttribute filter on the action method , I have not configured IAntiforegery seperately